# Not Like Operator Weird Result Count

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce-4

I have a table with 31,483 records in it. I would like to search this table using both a LIKE and a NOT LIKE operator. The user can select the Contains or the Does Not Contain option.

When I do a LIKE the where clause is as follows

```
WHERE Model LIKE '%test%'
```

Which filters the result set down to 1345 records - so all is fine and Dandy

**HOWEVER**

I expected that running a not like on the table would result in *n records where n = totalRowCount - LikeResultSet* which results in an expected record count of 30138 when running a NOT LIKE operation.

I ran this WHERE clause:

```
WHERE Model NOT LIKE '%test%'
```

However it returned 30526 records.

I am assuming there is some intricacy of the NOT LIKE operator I am not realising.

so my question

**Why arent I recieving a record count of TotalRows - LikeResults?**

I am using SQL Server Compact 4.0
C#
Visual Studio 2012

Comment: Do you have nulls? if Model is null it'll be neither LIKE nor NOT LIKE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if some Model values are *nulls*, e.g. for the simple artifitial table

```
  with data as (
    select 'test' as model
     union all
    select 'abc'
     union all
    select 'def'
     union all
    select null -- <- That's vital
 )
```

you'll get

```
  -- 4 items
  select count(1)
    from data 

  -- 1 item: 'test'
  select count(1)
    from data 
   where model like '%test%'

  -- 2 items: 'abc' and 'def'
  select count(1)
    from data 
   where model not like '%test%'
```

And so *1 + 2 != 4*

Answer (score 0):

There is `NULL` value in your data and `LIKE` will ignore `NULL` value.

You can test this and see the behavior.

```
create table a
(
    nama varchar(30)
)

insert into a values ('iswanto');
insert into a values (null);
insert into a values ('joko');
insert into a values ('tukul');
insert into a values ('iswanto2');
insert into a values (null);

select * from a where nama  like '%w%' // 2 record
select * from a where nama not like '%w%' // 2 record
```

If you want include `NULL` value in your query, try use [COALESCE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174075%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) function.

```
select * from a where coalesce(nama, '')  like '%w%' // 2 record
select * from a where coalesce(nama, '')  not like '%w%' // 4 record
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `WHERE` clause should be changed to `WHERE ISNULL(Model,'') LIKE '%test%'` to replace NULLs with empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

because like and not like ignores null field value to set try isnull() function in query.

```
  WHERE Model NOT LIKE '%test%' || isnull(Model)
```

it will return 30138 records